# Graphing by time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a data set (~2000 rows) with the following form:

```
+---------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Datetime            | n1  | n2  | n3  | n4  | tot |
+---------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 2008-08-02 12:25:00 | 20  | 5   | 2   | 3   | 30  |
+---------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I'd like to graph this data using a **Stacked Area** chart in Excel 2003. Where I'm having difficulty is I'd like to present the chart on a scale of each hour. Could someone please provide the steps for producing a Stacked Area chart using time scale?

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps you need to follow. I'm using a Pivot Chart, as suggested by [Longhorn213](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2469/longhorn213). While you have the table selected:

1. Select **Data -> PivotTable and PivotChart Report ...**
2. Select the Radio Button for **PivotChart report (with PivotTable report)**
3. Hit the **Finish** button
   You should now have two new tabs in the spreadsheet. One will have an empty chart and the other will have an empty pivot table. Select the sheet with the empty pivot table. Then:
4. Drag the **Date** field from the **Pivot Table Field List** to the area in the pivot table marked **Drop Row Fields Here**
   You should now see EVERY time stamp listed in the row.
5. Right click on the **Date** header in the Row and select **Group and Show Detail -> Group**
6. Highlight that you want to group by **Hours** and then hit the **OK** button
   Note that if your data spans several days/months, you **MUST** select both **Days** and **Months** in addition to **Hours** to further order the data.
7. Drag the **n1** field into the area marked **Drop Data Items Here**
8. Drag the **n2** field over top of the n1 data and drop it
   This will cause a new row header called **Data** to appear beside the **Date** header.
9. Drag the new **Data** header to the area marked **Total** and drop it there
   You now have the basic structure of the table that you want.
10. Drag the **n3** and **n4** fields into the data area, completing the table you want
    Now you can switch back over to the new chart sheet that was created. You should see the default type of chart with all your data.
11. Right click on the **Chart Area** and select **Chart Type...**
12. Select the type of chart you want

And we're done! I'll check back later and clarify anything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot Tables for it.

With Pivot Tables you have the data in one tab and then create a pivot table and summarize them by time.  I would refer to the Help with Excel for more on Pivot Tables.